# How can I achieve a rolling shutter effect including material changes?

Tags: rendering, animation, effects

I need an improved rolling shutter effect. For example I am rotating a cube by 90 degrees and changing the color from yellow to blue at the same time. For this timeframe I use the rolling shutter effect from the Cycles renderer. While this works for the rotation (cube appears twisted), it unfortunately doesn't work for the color change (bottom of the cube should have been blue).

[image: twisted cube]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you post a video here for non-tiktokers?

Comment: "*You probably have seen this TikTok trend*" We have not, could you illustrate? Please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: So you want it to be a still image? Initially I thought maybe an animation showing how the still is generated. Like here: https://youtu.be/nP1elMR5qjc?t=296

Comment: Yes a still image would be the goal. I guess I can achieve the effekt by rendering the whole animation and than do some kind of after effects. But this would be a waste of resources. Maybe a python script that renders only a small slices of each frame ans stitching them together afterwords would do the trick...